# Couchbase Lite Views Replication

Tags: android, nosql, couchdb, replication, couchbase

Is it possible to replicate views from CouchDB server to Couchbase Lite Android DB ?

I have database on CouchDB server and 2 views.

When I replicate, there are 2 documents named `_design/....` so view definitions are synchronized, but when I'm calling `database.getAllViews()` - it returns empty list.

So my question is - how to use views defined at CouchDB server ?

Greetings.

Comment: Note that CouchDB and Couchbase are two totally different products - while Couchbase began from CouchDB it has significantly evolved away from it now. I doubt there's any straightforward way to get CouchDB and Couchbase (lite) to interoperate.

Comment: OK, I'll try with Couchbase Server later. Thanks for advice !